# getImageData and .data()

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to modify dynamically all the pixels in an image previously drawn in canvas but, don't know why, I can't. Here is the code.

**Mark-Up:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas style="width:200px;height:200px;background:blue" id="prueba"></canvas>
        <p style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:100px;background:red;width:100px" onclick="changeIt()"> Change</p>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the script (main.js):**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var c=document.getElementById("prueba");
    ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="green";
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,50,50);
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'img/p.jpg';
    base_image.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, 10, 10);
    }
});

function changeIt(){
    var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1);
    var red=imgData.data[1];
    console.log(imgData.length);
    console.log(red);
}
```

I obtain this error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

It makes no sense because I'm working locally.

Comment: You can **not** load cross domain images into a canvas and modify them, it goes agains the same-origin policy.

Comment: I supposed it... But, what is the solution or recommendation to deal with it?

Comment: Hosting the image on the same domain as the canvas is the obvious solution ?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood anything, but the image is locally hosted in the same place of the index.

Comment: The error states that the canvas was tainted, so somewhere cross domain content is insterted in the canvas.

Comment: Are you running the page via a server, or simply by double-clicking it in the file-manager of your OS? (Hint: you need to be running it via a server - So, `localhost/somePage.html`, rather than `file:///C:/someDir/somePage.html`)